# Can I build both iOS and Android apps using react native on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: react-native, ubuntu

So I just started out to learn react-native but I found out that to build both iOS and Android requires OS X. I use Ubuntu but I haven't heard or read from somewhere about Linux writing react-native applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can't build iOS app without XCode. Maybe you can do this using virtual machine.

Comment: Yeah! That's what I should do
Thanks @Sabish.M